# Problem in understanding the proof of closure of topological closure is closure.

Tags: general-topology, proof-explanation

Well, I was following the proof of [Closure of Topological Closure equals Closure](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Closure_of_Topological_Closure_equals_Closure); here is the proof:

> It follows directly from Set is Subset of its Topological Closure that:
>
> $$\overline{H} \subseteq \overline{\left(\overline{H}\right)}$$
>
> $\Box$
>
> Let $x \in \overline{\left(\overline{H}\right)}$
>
> Then from Condition for Point being in Closure, any $U$ which is open in $T$ such that $x\in U$ contains some $y\in \overline{H}$
>
> If we consider $U$ as an open set containing $y,$ it follows that:
>
> $$U \cap H \ne \varnothing$$
>
> **Hence, $x\in \overline{H}$.**
>
> $\blacksquare$

I could all but the last line; how did they conclude lastly that $x\in \overline{H}?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It follows from the definition. The closure of $A$ is the smallest closed set containing $A$.

By definition we have $\overline{H} \subset \overline{\overline{H}}$.

Since $\overline{H}$ is a closed set containing $\overline{H}$, we have
$\overline{\overline{H}} \subset \overline{H}$, and so
$\overline{\overline{H}} = \overline{H}$

**Addendum**:

A point $x$ is in the closure of $A$ **iff** for all open $U$ that contain $x$, then $U \cap A \neq \emptyset$.

If $x \in \overline{\overline{H}}$ and $U$ is an open set containing $X$,
then $U \cap {\overline{H}} \neq \emptyset$. Since $U$ is open, and contains
a point in $\overline{H}$, then it must intersect $H$ and so $U \cap H \neq \emptyset$. Since this is true for all open $U$ containing $x$, we see that
$x \in \overline{H}$.

Comment: This is right, of course, but it's not answering directly OP's question about his proof.

Comment: I added a direct answer.

Comment: @copper.hat, can you please explain why this is true "Since $U$ is open, and contains
a point in $\overline{H}$, then it must intersect $H$ "?

Answer (score 0):

For $x \bar {\bar H}:$ Observe that any open set $U$ containing $x$ is  an open nbhd of every point of $U.$ Now there exists $y\in U\cap \bar H,$ and every nbhd of $y$ intersects $H$ (because $y\in \bar H$) so there exists $z\in U\cap H.$ That is $U\cap H\ne \emptyset$ for every open $U$ containing $x,$ so $x\in \bar H .$